# Can we execute the alert message using the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we alert the message using the following function ??

```
var run_databases = function() {
    alert('welcome');
};

window.setTimeout(run_databases, 1000);
```

Comment: why dont you just try? Thats not an jquery answer

Comment: Can we alert the message by invoking the function for run_databases ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name the function or assign it to a variable:

```js
var run_databases = function() {
  alert('welcome');
};

// You need to name this function
function setTimeOutFoo() {

  window.setTimeout(run_databases, 1000);

};

// Or assign the unnamed function to a variable
var setTimeOutVar = function() {

  window.setTimeout(run_databases, 1000);

};

setTimeOutFoo(); // Calling the function
setTimeOutVar();
```

You can try something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('Page has finished loading');  
  
  //I am adding a time out so you can see the loading
  // You can remove the "setTimeout(function () {"
  // And you can also remove the "}, 2000);"
  
  setTimeout(function () { // Remove this line
    
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Page Loaded";
    
  }, 2000); // Remove this line
  
};
```

```html
<p id="loading">Page Loading...</p>
```

The easiest way to add a tooltip to a button is:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.setAttribute('title', 'This is the tool tip set in JavaScript');
```

```html
<!-- Done with JavaScript -->
<button id="btn">Hover here!</button> 

<!-- Done in the HTML -->
<button id="btn" title="This is tool tip set in HTML">No! Hover here :)</button>
```

Comment: Can we display a loading window using in the similar way of coding ??

Answer (score 1):

No need for the other function wrapping (closure) :

```js
var run_databases = function() {
  alert('welcome');
};

window.setTimeout(run_databases, 1000);
```

Comment: Can we display a loading window using in the similar way of coding ??

Answer (score 0):

You're using a self invoking anonymous function, but your syntax is wrong:

```
var run_databases = function() {
  alert('welcome');
};

(function(){
   window.setTimeout(run_databases, 1000);
})();
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/qm6r76kq/)

Comment: Post a new question, people aren't here to code for you. Read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask